# global variable modification tcl

Tags: tcl, global

I have a program that essentially looks like this:

```
set var1 x

set var2 y

set var3 z

proc one {} {

     global var1
     set var1 "hello"
}

proc two {} {

     puts $var1
}
```

However, the output always seems to be x, not "hello" when I call proc one then proc two.  Am I making a syntax error? Or is this not possible in tcl?

Comment: In proc `two`, unless specifying `global`, you can't access `var1`. By the way, what you are expecting should work. May be you are missing something. Give the complete flow of code.

Answer (score 0):

You're not making a *syntax* error so much as a semantic error. Variables in procedures are *always* local (unless they're specified using qualified names). That means that `two` is talking about its own `var1`, not the global one. To use the global one, you need to explicitly ask for it:

```
proc two {} {
    global var1
    puts $var1
}
```

Or alternatively, using the fully-qualified name of the global variable:

```
proc two {} {
    puts $::var1
}
```

I recommend using `global` normally; it's both clearer and faster (provided you're using the variable a few times, which is usually the case in real code).